# Separating real and dummy windows returned by CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I am creating a window switcher for macOS.

I am using [`CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455137-cgwindowlistcopywindowinfo) to get the list of open windows.

```
    let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo([.excludeDesktopElements], kCGNullWindowID)
```

I am not using the [`optionOnScreenOnly`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgwindowlistoption/1454105-optiononscreenonly) option along with `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` because that excludes off-[space](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh14112/mac) windows.

However, this leads to certain dummy windows also getting included in the list of windows. For example, there is a window present for each open tab on Xcode. There is also an additional invisible window for VLC player apart from the actual window. These windows aren't present if I use `optionOnScreenOnly`.

**Is there a way to separate these dummy windows from actual windows?**

I have explored the `kCGWindowLayer` and `kCGWindowStoreType` keys in the dictionaries returned by `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` but couldn't tell the windows apart.

**Edit**:

I am open to both Swift and Objective-C solutions, as well as private API calls.

**Edit 2**:

I know this is possible to do because the app [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/) handles these cases correctly.

Comment: From the FAQ of Witch: "Witch uses a public API (Application Programming Interface) known as the Accessibility API to get information about open windows in other programs."

Comment: Do you have a minimum working example that I could inspect and try to help you??

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this captures all the cases you're interested in, but if we take the array of dictionaries returned by `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` and group the entries by `kCGWindowNumber` (the window ID), it looks like we'll end up with one of three cases:

- Only one dictionary entry has that window number (it's a simple widow, which may be on or off screen)
- Several dictionaries have that window id, and only one of them in the group has the key `kCGWindowIsOnscreen` set to 1: the others either lack the key or have it set to 0. This means we have a window with several tabs, and the entry with `kCGWindowIsOnscreen` set is the visible tab.
- Several dictionaries have that window id, and none have the key `kCGWindowIsOnscreen` set to 1 (it is missing or set to 0 in all cases). This means we have a window with several tabs that is currently off-screen.

I'm assuming you're probably already filtering out anything that isn't in layer 0 (`kCGWindowLayer = 0`). It seems that most of the things that we visually perceive as a 'window' are in layer 0 (status menu items seem to be in layers with single or low double digits; widgets seem to be up around layer 100...).

I don't see any simple, direct way to get at this, but you should be able to build this logic into something workable.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a different approach, by checking what apps are running and visible using the following:

```
let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter{ $0.activationPolicy == .regular }
```

If you `print(runningApps)` you will get a list of apps currently ran in your workspace.

Hope this helps.